# Cannot access the eCampus website of my university

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to access my university's ecampus website(using Mozilla Firefox) and I cannot access it(the page remains blank).

The link is the following: http://ecampus.ucn.dk

--I can access the page from windows and I'm using tethering to have Internet on Linux and I can access the website from my phone--

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using Chromium Browser an authentication windows opens! https://imgur.com/7WlIEtA

Comment: Did you used it on linux?

Comment: It works on Chromium Browser but not on Mozillaaa Firefox. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Yes I used Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: @konrad: Same goes for Firefox v.20: http://www.imagebam.com/image/6c2a9f359860064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/firefox-30-blocks-access-on-non-windows-platforms-to-sharepoint-and-iis-sites/

1. Open Firefox
2. In the address bar, enter the following: about:config
3. If prompted, click on the I’ll be careful, I promise! button.
4. Search for the following:

   ```
   network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1
   ```
5. Once the `network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1` setting is located, double-click on the setting. That should change the entry in the Value column from `false` to `true`.
6. Once the `network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1` setting has been set to `true`, close the Firefox browser window.
7. Open a new browser window and attempt to access the SharePoint-based or IIS-backed site. You should now be able to log in.